# Convert JNDI DataSource Bean to JEE:jndi-lookup

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, jndi

I have a Spring setting as follows.

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://jndi.myURL.com:1099</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
            <prop key="jnp.disableDiscovery">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/mysql"/><!-- DataSource Name -->
    <property name="resourceRef" value="false"/>
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
</bean>
```

I want to convert that in JEE tag format.

I want to define my DataSrouce as

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/mysql" resource-ref="false" >
    <jee:environment>
        ....
    </jee:environment>
</jee:jndi-lookup>
```

Is there a way to define that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can share the definition with:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment" ref="remoteEnv" />
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="wcDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/wc-mysql" resource-ref="false" environment-ref="remoteEnv" />

<util:properties id="remoteEnv">
    <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://jndi.myURL.me:1099</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
    <prop key="jnp.disableDiscovery">true</prop>
</util:properties>
```

This way you can still refer jndiTemplate elsewhere, if it is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your time, I found the issue. I found that issue but not quite really getting to the right solution. Following is the code snippets that is working for me.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="wcDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/wc-mysql" resource-ref="false">
    <jee:environment>
      java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
      java.naming.provider.url=jnp://jndi.myURL.me:1099
      java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
      jnp.disableDiscovery=true
    </jee:environment>
</jee:jndi-lookup>
```